# IOS 7 Safari (as well as OSX 10.9) Credit Card prompt "not now" causing issues

Tags: macos, ios7, safari, icloud, keychain

When users select "Not Now" to iCloud Keychain credit card prompt (IOS 7 Safari), there are problems with form submission.

On IOS 7 Safari, the form won't submit.

Reloading the form solves the problem, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: ever found a solution to this? autocomplete="off" in fields should disable this feature

Comment: autocomplete="off" did not work; IOS 7 Safari manages to try to ask to remember anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem was caused by the form containing an input of type="password" . As soon as I removed that input, or changed it to "text", the form would submit normally after the user clicked "not now".

Answer (score 0):

We were running into this exact issue. As Guy Thomas mentioned, it was due to having password fields in the form with the CC fields.

After lots of testing, I determined that the password fields could be switched to a different `type` before submitting the form (in our case, just switched to `hidden`). This allowed the form to submit even after choosing "Not Now" in the dialog.

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    try{
        $("input[type=password]").attr("type", "hidden");
    } catch(ex){
        try {
            $("input[type=password]").prop("type", "hidden");
        } catch(ex) {}
    }          
});
```

I added the try/catches because depending on browser/jquery version, changing the type attribute would error.